# API Connect SOAPFault handling

Tags: apiconnect

How can I map SOAP Fault to REST JSON object in API Connect?

I am handling SOAP Faults by check "Stop on Error" in my Invoke component, however, I don´t know how to get fault body and set in a JSON object in my message.body, for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve this issue.

In my case, my problem was that the invoke´s variable output exposed me its JSON body as a NodeList XML, so I couldn´t retrieve any information of this.

I got this variable and transformed it to XML in a gatewayscript

```js
var nodeList = apim.getvariable('<responseServiceVariable>.body');

apim.setvariable('message.headers.content-type', 'application/xml')
apim.setvariable('message.body', nodeList);
```

After that, I used the XML-to-JSON component.

And then, I transformed response with other gatewayscript

```js
apim.readInputAsJSON(function (error, json) {


  if (error) {}

  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json)
  .replace(/\$/g,'value');
  
  var jsonReplaced = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  var envelope = jsonReplaced['s:Envelope'];
  var body = envelope['s:Body'];
  var fault = body['s:Fault'];
  var faultstring = fault['faultstring'];
  var moreInformation = faultstring['value'];

  var httpMessage = "My httpMessage"

  var error = {"httpCode": 400, "httpMessage": httpMessage, "moreInformation": moreInformation}

  apim.setvariable('message.headers.content-type', 'application/json')
  apim.setvariable('message.status.code', 400);
  apim.setvariable('message.body', error);
});
```

Comment: olar vc eu estava me perguntando exatamente a msm coisa